# Binary search tree Main fun where get AttributeError: 'BTreeWordFinder' object has no attribute 'showDepth'

Tags: python-3.x, binary-search-tree

> ```
> I am stuck where is the problem define showDepth for running time a Btree code 
>
>  def MaxDepth(root,height):
>         # condition to stop recursion
>         if root == None:
>             return 0
>         else:
>             return -1
>
>          divide and conquer from root to deep and longest 
>         Depth_left = MaxDepth(root.left,height)
>         self.left = None
>         self.right = None
>         Depth_right = MinDepth(root.right,height)
>         MaxDepth = (Depth_left, Depth_right) + 1
>         # return the final result
>         if Depth_left > right_Depth:
>             return Depth_left + 1
>
>         else:
>             return rightDepth + 1
>         return showDepth
>  Second Part main fun 
>   def main():
>         '' 'main application method. Create the search engine, ask the user for the name of a text and in it search and display the words
> ```
>
> in a dictionary found, as well as display alphabetically sorted the
> words in the text and the depth of the tree '' '
> b = BTreeWordFinder(BTreeWordFinder.askFile())
> b.findOcurrencesInFile('dictionary.txt')
> b.viewIndex()
> b.showDepth()
>
> ```
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>  BTreeWordFinder.main()
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "D:/btree-word-finder-master/btree-word-finder-master/Code_and_texts/BTreeWordFinder.py",
> ```
>
> line 94, in 
> BTreeWordFinder.main()
> File "D:/btree-word-finder-master/btree-word-finder-master/Code_and_texts/BTreeWordFinder.py",
> line 90, in main
> b.showDepth()
> AttributeError: 'BTreeWordFinder' object has no attribute 'showDepth'

Comment: You are returning `showDepth`, but its not getting created anywhere.

Comment: Yes that the reasons i am confuse do you help me to guide about it